# What does instance variable that looks like this @my_variable inside a self.method mean?

Tags: ruby

I dont understand what an instance variable inside a class method does. Below code makes no sense to me. How can a class method manipulate an instance variable? I can call a class method without even having an instance.

```
def self.schema
    return @schema if @schema
    DB.table_info(table) do |row|
      @schema[row['name']] = row['type']
    @schema
end
```

Edit: follow up question after  @Aetherus's answer.
What is `first_name` in the below code example? Why cant i access it as a class variable since it is inside class scope? Why does all 3 methods give me errors?

```
   class Person
     #class scope
      first_name = "jimmy"

       # expected error beacuse it would treat as local variable
      def print_name
        #instance scope
       first_name
      end

       #to my understanding this should work, but it doesnt. i dont know why
      def print_name_2
        #instance scope
        #with self.class i should be able to access class scope?
        self.class.first_name
      end  

      #to my understading this should work, but it doesnt. I dont know why.   
      def self.print_name
        #class scope
        #inside class scope, i should able to access first_name?
        first_name
       end

    end
```

Comment: Your class is an object too. Instead of defining specific methods within the class it's instantiated from (namely Class), it's best  to define any custom methods within its singleton class. Here any defined instance variables are available across all methods within the singleton class which can be very handy.

Comment: Variables that start with a single `@` are *instance variables*. Variables that start with a lowercase letter are *local variables*. May I suggest that you read some Ruby tutorial and/or book? Instance variables and local variables are really one of the very first things that should be explained in any halfway decent tutorial. Also, the fact that Ruby doesn't have class methods should be explained there, as does the fact that classes are objects.

Comment: It's not really a good idea to follow up a question with another question especially when you've already accepted an answer. Your second question demonstrates that you do (as advised above) need to work your way through a few tutorials. There are things you should take the time to understand. Check out Codecademy or Learn to Program by Chris Pine.

Comment: JörgWMittag, sagarpandya82, I am currently reading two books right now, The Well-Grounded Rubyist and Poodr by Sandi Metz.  In fact, the problem above was explained in the book but i couldnt understand. Sometimes, i need to read two explanations to understand it. The book explained it as **"Since those are self methods defined on the class object,
@schema is actually an instance variable of the class itself, not
on an instance -- so weʼll only have one for each class or
subclass, not one for each instance variable "** . With Aetherus answer i was able to understand it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I know that `first_name` is a local variable but just not sure why `self.print_name` wasnt able access `first_name` even though they are in the same scope. Not trying to be lazy, specific questions like these are very hard for me to get out of the book, Sorry.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I will not add follow up question again, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, these instance variables belong to the class, not the instances of that class.

To understand it, you need to know more about Ruby.

### Classes are objects

In Ruby, all the classes are just objects of type `Class`.

```
String.class  #=> Class
Array.class   #=> Class
Class.class   #=> Class
```

And you can define anonymous classes by instantiating `Class`

```
foo = Class.new do
  # Here you can define methods
end

foo.new  #=> an instance of an anonymous class
```

Because classes are objects, they can have instance variables too.

### Gate of scopes

There are 4 keywords that triggers scope switching: `module`, `class`, `def` and `do` (for blocks). Here I only show the `class` and `def`.

```
# in the scope of main

class Foo
  # in the scope of Foo

  def self.bar
    # still in the scope of Foo
  end

  # in the scope of Foo

  def bar
    # in the scope of an instance of Foo
  end

  # back to the scope of Foo again
end

# back to the scope of main
```

The instance variables defined in a scope belongs to the **current object** (a.k.a. `self`) of that scope. In the previous example, if you define a instance variable in the scope of `Foo`, that instance variable belongs to the `self` of that scope, which is the class `Foo`.

Comment: Where do you put the scope of main? Where does it belong in module, class, def,  or do? I think it is module scope, right? It is not def, class, or do(blocks) so there only one choice left which is module. So if i open up irb and start with something like x = 19. x is in module scope?

Comment: The top level scope (main) is just a scope of an `Object`. You can run `self.class` in the top level scope to verify it.